# Laravel redirect after delete item

Tags: laravel-5

In my Laravel app, I want to delete an item and redirect immediately after that to the home page. Ideally, I want to do this purely in the routes file:

```
Route::get('event/{event}/delete', ['as' => 'events_delete', 'uses' => 'EventsController@destroy', function () {
    return Redirect::route('events_list');
}] );
```

In my destroy function I have the following:

```
public function destroy(Event $event)
{
    $event->delete();
}
```

The delete itself works (after refresh), but the redirect part does not seem to work. How can I redirect to the homepage immediately after the delete happened?

Answer (score 0):

You either use the controller or the closure but not both, I don't think you are allowed to use them both.

But in your controller you can set the redirect like this:

```
public function destroy(RequestEvent $event)
{
    $event->delete();
    return redirect()->route('your_home_route');
}
```

Comment: Indeed thanks. I wanted to combine two things because it seemed logical. Looks like this could be a good feature for the next Laravel releases :-)